# How to retain numeric entity when reading xml file?

Tags: xml, node.js

I am using Node.js and reading  text file that contains xml tag.   The text file contains

```
  Student Writer&#8217;s
```

After reading file

```
 fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: 'UTF-8'}, function(err,data){
  if (!err){

    var xmldoc = parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
    console.log("xmdata"+xmldoc);
  }

 }
```

The output of the file is

```
 Student Writer’s Manual
```

Note:  I am not reading in browser.   I checked in edit mode(in nodepad)

But i want to retain the xml file as it is.

Like

```
 Student Writer&#8217;s
```

How to retain numeric entity in output file?

Any one assist me?

Thanks in advance.